# How can I enable pinch to zoom in Finder on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, finder

After upgrading to Lion the pinch-to-zoom seems to be gone in Finder.  Didn't even find an option for it in system preferences. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preference for this used to be located in Finder>Preferences. It's no longer available and after some research online, it looks like no one has discovered a way to turn this on using a plist edit.

You might consider telling Apple about how much you miss this:
http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: that's what i thought, submitted a comment.  thanks.